# Camel Jetty SSL configuration: load keychain from a relative path

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel, jetty, relative-path

I'm trying to config SSL for Camel Jetty. The project is a WAR running on Tomcat7, and I'm using a Maven-Tomcat plugin for debugging.

This is the code of the SSL configuration method, under my `RouteBuilder` class:

```
private void configureSslForJetty()
{
    KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
    ksp.setResource("ssl/keychain.p12");
    ksp.setType("PKCS12");
    ksp.setPassword("my_pass");

    KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
    kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);
    kmp.setKeyPassword("password");

    SSLContextParameters scp = new SSLContextParameters();
    scp.setKeyManagers(kmp);

    JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
    jettyComponent.setSslContextParameters(scp);
}
```

Note that the keychain path is relative to the class itself.
This configuration works perfectly on an external tomcat, but when using the maven plugin - it throws an `IOException` as it couldn't find the keychain file.

How can I define the path relatively in the best way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do so by reading the keystore as a resource.

That's the final code:

```
KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();

URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/ssl/keychain.p12");
File file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
String keyChainPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

ksp.setResource(keyChainPath);
ksp.setType("PKCS12");
ksp.setPassword("my_pass");
```